# Matrix with continuous entries

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $S$ is a metric space, if $a_{11},..,a_{mn}$ are real continuous functions on $S$ and if, for each $p\in S$, $A_p$ is the linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$ whose matrix has entries $a_{ij}(p)$, then the mapping $p\to A_p$ is a continuous mapping of $S$ into $L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$.

I guess that here we must use this $$\lVert A\rVert\leq \left(\sum \limits_{i,j}a_{ij}^2\right)^{1/2}$$ but unfortunately i don't know how.

Can anyone show full proof?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already pointed out one way is the following: write 
$$
\lVert A(p_1)-A(p_2)\rVert^2 \le \sum_{ij} \left\lvert a_{ij}(p_1)-a_{ij}(p_2)\right\rvert^2, $$
which shows that any continuity property of the scalar-valued functions $p\mapsto a_{ij}(p)$ is inherited by the matrix valued function. For example, if all entries are Lipschitz or Hölder continuous, then so is the matrix; if all entries are merely continuous, then so is the matrix.

Comment: I am needed only in continuity. Let $p\in S$ and $\epsilon>0$ be given then $\exists \delta>0$ such that for any $p_1\in S$ with $d(p_1,p)<\delta$ we have $|a_{ij}(p)-a_{ij}(p_1)|<\frac{\epsilon^2}{n^2}$. Then $\lVert A(p_1)-A(p_2)\rVert<\epsilon$. Are my reasonings right? (if our matrix has $n^2$ elements).

Comment: Yes that's it. (Modulo the fact that you should require $|a_{ij}(p_1)-a_{ij}(p)|^2\le \epsilon^2 / n^4$).

Comment: Sorry that i am intervene but i think that here in denominator sufficient to take $n^2$.

Comment: @RFZ: Yes of course. You are right